# How can I multithread this code snippet in C++ with Eigen

Tags: c++, multithreading, eigen

I'm trying to implement a faster version of the following code fragment:

```
Eigen::VectorXd dTX = (( (XPSF.array() - x0).square() + (ZPSF.array() - z0).square() ).sqrt() + txShift)*fs/c + t0*fs;
Eigen::VectorXd Zsq = ZPSF.array().square();   
Eigen::MatrixXd idxt(XPSF.size(),nc);
        
for (int i = 0; i < nc; i++) {
      idxt.col(i) = ((XPSF.array() - xe(i)).square() + Zsq.array()).sqrt()*fs/c + dTX.array();
      idxt.col(i) = (abs(XPSF.array()-xe(i)) <= ZPSF.array()*0.5/fnumber).select(idxt.col(i),-1);
}
```

The sample array sizes I'm working with right now are:

XPSF: Column Vector of 591*192 coefficients (113,472 total values in the column vector)

ZPSF: Same size as XPSF

xe: RowVector of 192 coefficients

idxt: Matrix of 113,472x192 size

Current runs with gcc and -msse2 and -o3 optimization yield an average time of ~0.08 seconds for the first line of the loop and ~0.03 seconds for the second line of the loop. I know that runtimes are platform dependent, but I believe that this still can be much faster. A commercial software performs the operations I'm trying to do here in ~two orders of magnitude less time. Also, I suspect my code is a bit amateurish right now!

I've tried reading over Eigen documentation to understand how vectorization works, where it is implemented and how much of this code might be "implicitly" parallelized by Eigen, but I've struggled to keep track of the details. I'm also a bit new to C++ in general, but I've seen the documentation and other resources regarding std::thread and have tried to combine it with this code, but without much success.

Any advice would be appreciated.

**Update:**

[image: Here's the output of dxdiag in response to a comment]

**Update 2**

I would upvote Soleil's answer because it contains helpful information if I had the reputation score for it. However, I should clarify that I would like to first figure out what optimizations I can do without a GPU. I'm convinced (albeit without OpenMP) Eigen's inherent multithreading and vectorization won't speed it up any further (unless there are unnecessary temporaries being generated). How could I use something like std::thread to explicitly parellelize this? I'm struggling to combine both std::thread and Eigen to this end.

Comment: Can you add to your question the hardware you're using ? In particular the CPU model and cores/threads, and your GPUs (discrete and CPU's if any).

Comment: I added a screenshot of dxdiag summarizing this info. I'm not sure why the GPU would be relevant, I'm not actively using it with how my code is currently written.

Comment: Use `-march=native`. That unlocks the full instruction set of your CPU.

Comment: Can you add a high-level description of what the code is meant to do?

Comment: Can you generate a benchmark with randomly-generated data that reproduces the performance issue? It looks like you're generating unnecessary temporaries, but it's hard to say without playing around.

Comment: -march=native doesn't improve performance. I do think I might be generating unnecessary temporaries, but I'm not sure how to figure out where those temporaries are.

Also, this is part of source code for a MEX function written in Matlab. My "benchmarking" is simply commenting out portions of my code, compiling it, and running the function using tic, toc in matlab. When I do that, I've found the two lines in the for loop are what seem to be taking up most of the time. That was what the above timings refer to.

Comment: @drakon101 the omp is your explicit map/reduce using (implicit) threads and gathering results. You want to avoid using `std::thread`, which will be a tremendous overhead compared to omp pragmas. It's like writing in assembly the equivalent code you can write in c++ and compile.

Comment: @drakon101 std:: thread is more for async/await/join programming. However if you "struggle with that", you want to ask another question with what you did so far with std::thread (without which your question will be closed very quickly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OpenMP**

If your CPU has enough many cores and threads, usually a simple and quick first step is to invoke OpenMP by adding the pragma:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < nc; i++)
```

and compile with `/openmp` (cl) or `-fopenmp` (gcc) or just `-ftree-parallelize-loops` with gcc in order to auto unroll the loops.

This will do a map reduce and the map will occur over the number of parallel threads your CPU can handle (8 threads with the 7700HQ).

In general you also can [set a clause `num_threads(n)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/openmp/reference/openmp-directives?view=msvc-160#example-7) where n is the desired number of threads:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
```

Where I used 8 since the 7700HQ can handle 8 concurrent threads.

**TBB**

You also can [unroll your loop with TBB](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneAPI-samples/blob/master/DirectProgramming/DPC%2B%2BFPGA/Tutorials/Features/loop_unroll/README.md):

```
#pragma unroll
for (int i = 0; i < nc; i++)
```

**threading integrated with eigen**

With Eigen you [can add](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html)

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=n ./my_program
omp_set_num_threads(n);
Eigen::setNbThreads(n);
```

**remarks with multithreading with eigen**

However, in the [FAQ](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#How_does_Eigen_compare_to_BLAS.2FLAPACK.3F):

> currently Eigen parallelizes only general matrix-matrix products (bench), so it doesn't by itself take much advantage of parallel hardware."

In general, the improvement with OpenMP is not always here, so benchmark the release build. Another way is to make sure that you're using vectorized instructions.

Again, from the [FAQ/vectorization](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#Vectorization):

> How can I enable vectorization?
>
> You just need to tell your compiler to enable the corresponding
> instruction set, and Eigen will then detect it. If it is enabled by
> default, then you don't need to do anything. On GCC and clang you can
> simply pass -march=native to let the compiler enables all instruction
> set that are supported by your CPU.
>
> On the x86 architecture, SSE is not enabled by default by most
> compilers. You need to enable SSE2 (or newer) manually. For example,
> with GCC, you would pass the -msse2 command-line option.
>
> On the x86-64 architecture, SSE2 is generally enabled by default, but
> you can enable AVX and FMA for better performance
>
> On PowerPC, you have to use the following flags: -maltivec
> -mabi=altivec, for AltiVec, or -mvsx for VSX-capable systems.
>
> On 32-bit ARM NEON, the following: -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp|hard,
> depending if you are on a softfp/hardfp system. Most current
> distributions are using a hard floating-point ABI, so go for the
> latter, or just leave the default and just pass -mfpu=neon.
>
> On 64-bit ARM, SIMD is enabled by default, you don't have to do
> anything extra.
>
> On S390X SIMD (ZVector), you have to use a recent gcc (version >5.2.1)
> compiler, and add the following flags: -march=z13 -mzvector.

**multithreading with cuda**

Given the size of your arrays, you want to try to offload to a GPU to reach the microsecond; in that case you would have (typically) as many threads as the number of elements in your array.

For a simple start, if you have an nvidia card, you want to look at [cublas](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html), which also allows you to use the tensor registers (fused multiply add, etc) of the last generations, unlike regular kernel.

Since eigen is a header only library, it makes sense that [you could use it in a cuda kernel](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicCUDA.html).

You also may implements everything "by hand" (ie., without eigen) with regular kernels. This is a nonsense in terms of engineering, but common practice in an education/university project, in order to understand everything.

**multithreading with OneAPI and Intel GPU**

Since you have a skylake architecture, you also can [unroll your loop on your CPU's GPU with OneAPI](http://%20https://oneapi.team/tattle/oneAPI-samples/-/tree/master/DirectProgramming/DPC++/ParallelPatterns/loop-unroll):

```
// Unroll loop as specified by the unroll factor.
#pragma unroll unroll_factor
for (int i = 0; i < nc; i++)
```

(from the [sample](https://oneapi.team/tattle/oneAPI-samples/-/blob/master/DirectProgramming/DPC++/ParallelPatterns/loop-unroll/src/loop-unroll.cpp)).

Comment: What does that first line of Eigen code: "OMP_NUM_THREADS=n ./my_program" mean? The syntax is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: @drakon101 it's setting env variable and then starting your program.